# number of identical ids in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a data frame with a varying number of group-ids and corresponding events.

```
Group   DiffDate    eventNumber
58390   0           0
58390   1765        0
24979   0           0
24979   61          0
24979   84          0
24979   1003        0
24979   1095        0
```

For final evaluation I need the serial number of the events by group, like this:

```
Group   DiffDate    eventNumber
58390   0           0
58390   1765        1
24979   0           0
24979   61          1
24979   84          2
24979   1003        3
24979   1095        4
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: No need in `plyr`, just do `with(df, ave(Group, Group, FUN = seq)) - 1L`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Group) %>% mutate(eventNumber = row_number()-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
library(plyr)
ddply(data,.(Group),function(x) x$eventNumber = 0:(nrow(x)-1))
```

This is provided that they're all sorted.  If they're not, you can just do that in the function in `ddply`.

Comment: This won't reach the exact desired output.